# Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Payment\Gateway\Config\ValueHandlerPoolInterface?

Tags: magento2, interface

After updating a shop to 2.4.6-p4, I am getting this error in a custom extension. The Interface file is there, I checked, so it must be some other problem.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

The full error is: `Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Payment\Gateway\Config\ValueHandlerPoolInterface in /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50`

I compiled, deployed and so on, nothing helps.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when upgrading stripe payments module to 4.0.0
the cause was, that the definition for the model changed to a virtualType

As we are using app:config:dump to store our config in config.php, we deleted the model entry and rerun a:c:d and the correct VirtualType occured

```
'stripe_payments_checkout' => [
    'active' => '1',
    'model' => 'StripeIntegration\\Payments\\Model\\Method\\Checkout',
    'sort_order' => '2',
    'title' => 'Stripe Checkout',
],
```

to

```
'model' => 'RedirectFlowFacade',
```

check new virtual types and update you config accordingliy.

This Error occurs when you directly instanciate ValueHandlerPoolInterface

```
/**
 * Default implementation of config value handlers pool.
 * This class designed to be base for virtual types.
 * Direct injection of this class is not recommended (inject ValueHandlerPoolInterface instead).
 * Inheritance from this class is not recommended (declare virtual type or implement ValueHandlerPoolInterface instead).
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
```

As doc says it is a base for virtual types...